# Is there any function similar to stristr() in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, php-5.2

Is there any function similar to `stristr()`? I want to use `stristr()`, but I can't because my PHP version is 5.2.9.

So I need a similar function which gives the same functionality.

```
<?php
$email = 'USER@EXAMPLE.com';
echo stristr($email, 'e'); // outputs ER@EXAMPLE.com
echo stristr($email, 'e', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0, outputs US
?>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [stripos](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) and [substr](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
echo substr($email, 0, stripos($email, 'e'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the 'before needle' functionality, this is trivial to implement yourself using the 2 parameter version....

```
 function stristr_bn($haystack, $needle)
 {
    $post=stristr($haystack, $needle);
    if ($post===false) return false;
    return substr($haystack, 0, strlen($haystack)-strlen($post)-strlen($needle));
 }
```

However this a very messy solution to the problem of parsing an ADRR_SPEC (regardless of implementation).